# The proper way of answering "What's this?" question

Tags: phrase-choice

To such a question like "What's this?", can I answer simply "A red pen" or should I always say "It's a red pen"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is correct to use a noun phrase "A red pen" in answer to such questions, except when a teacher specifically tells you to answer in "A full sentence". All the following are correct short responses.

> Who is the British Prime Minister?
>
> Boris Johnson

> Which chocolate do you want?
>
> The red one.

> How do you play violin?
>
> By practising.

> Why do you play violin?
>
> For fun

> When does the train leave?
>
> At two sharp.